# Clojure Convert PersistentVector of strings to PersistentVector of keywords

Tags: clojure, casting, type-conversion

Given the following vector: `["a" "b" "c"]` how can I convert it to `[:a :b :c]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mapv`:

```
(mapv keyword ["a" "b" "c"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that will result in `[":a" ":b" ":c"]` and `(:a (mapv keyword ["a" "b" "c"]))` will be nil

Comment: @RoniGadot - It will return `[:a :b :c]` which is what you asked for in the question. `(:a (mapv keyword ["a" "b" "c"]))`  returns `nil` because applying a keyword as a function will not search inside a vector. Please add any additional requirements to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`(vec (map keyword ["a" "b" "c"]))`